# DRF ModelSerializer make all fields Read Only without specifying them explicitely

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I was able to make read only model serializer, e.g.:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['name', 'ratio']
        read_only_fields = fields
```

However, I tend to add/remove fields to/from `Foo` frequently. It would be much easier not to update my serializer each time `Foo` is modified. The `fields = '__all__'` is very handy:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = fields
```

However, the `read_only_fields` does not accept `__all__` as a valid option and raises this exception:

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /api/foo/
Exception Value: The `read_only_fields` option must be a list or tuple. Got str.
```

How could I mark all fields as read only without explicitely adding each field to `read_only_fields` list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend `get_fields` method like this:

```
def get_fields(self):
    fields = super().get_fields()
    for field in fields.values():
        field.read_only = True
    return fields
```